# Maven lookout for specific repository

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have currently maven, jenkins, Nexus and git integrated and I'm kind of learning these tools.

My requirement is to tell maven to download my dependencies only from the repositories which I have mentioned in my pom.xml and not from my Nexus repository but its doing the opposite.

I have declared my Nexus releases and snapshots repositories under repository in my settings.xml. How do I tell maven to download my dependencies from specific repository and not from my Nexus repo.

Below is my pom.xml snippet

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
            <id>faq</id>
            <url>https://mycheck.github.com/faq/port/hist</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>dig</id>
     <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.org</groupId>
            <artifactId>faq</artifactId>
            <version>${faq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.net.myorg</groupId>
            <artifactId>retina</artifactId>
            <version>${retina-support.version}</version>
        </dependency>
            ........
            ......
 </dependencies>
```

Comment: This can't be done in your pom neither from Maven. This is the job for Nexus. Define the repository their and define appropriate routes in Nexus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *pom.xml* you have to override the repository configured in *settings.xml* to disable  both `snapshots` and `releases`. For example, considering a repository `my-repo` is configured in your *settings.xml* that you want to ignore in your project, your *pom.xml* must contains:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-repo</id> <!-- id must match settings.xml -->
        <name>My Private Repo</name>
        <url>http://repo.mycompany.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <!-- disable both snapshots and releases -->
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The `<id>` must match the one configured in your settings. As both `snapshots` and `releases` are set to false Maven will simply ignore the repository for your project. You must specify each repository you want to ignore this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion , will try and update . +1 for the detail explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand, but this can be done in the maven settings.xml file, inside this file you can specify the Repositories policy...

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/how-to-override-the-maven-local-repository-setting-838546993.html

Moreover the repo can be specified as parameter when you call the maven command you want to run.

This for more ref about the settings.html:
https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I'm looking to use a specific repository and not to override.. Thanks for looking into it though :)